# How do I pass arguments to a script piped to the Python interpreter on stdin?

Tags: python, pipe, command-line-arguments

I'm installing `poetry` using the `get-poetry.py` script, and I want to specify the version to install. To install the latest version I do

```
GET_POETRY_URL=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py
curl -sSL $GET_POETRY_URL | python
```

The `get-poetry.py` script takes an argument `--version`, but how do I pass that through?

```
curl -sSL $GET_POETRY_URL | python --version 1.1.4
```

prints the installed python version, rather than passing the argument through to the `get-poetry.py` script. I could save the script to a file and call it that way, but I'm doing this in a docker image and I don't want to deal with cleaning it up afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

```
curl -sSL $GET_POETRY_URL | python - --version 1.1.4
```

---

Using `-` as the script location when you call `python` will cause it to read from stdin. As usual, any arguments after the script location are passed to the script:

```
$ echo "import sys; print(sys.argv)" | python - --version 1.1.4
['-', '--version', '1.1.4']
```

Using `-` to mean stdin also works for many other unix tools:

```
$ echo hello | cat -
hello
```